# Positioning two aside blocks around a section using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a main `div` containing a `section` and two `aside` blocks on each side.

I wrote the following code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="main"> <!-- "main" tag not supported in IE -->
        <section>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </p>
        </section>
        <aside />
        <aside />
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width: 990px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: grey;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#main {
    display: flex;
}

aside {
    flex: 1;
    height: 400px;
}

#main aside:nth-child(1) {
    order: 1;
    background-color: black;
}
#main aside:nth-child(2) {
    order: 3;
    background-color: green;
}

section {
    background-color: yellow;
    flex: 2;
    order: 2;
}
```

and I get this:

[image: result]

Why do the two `aside` blocks appear (superimposed) at the right of the `section` block?

Edit:

I am expecting something like this:
[image: expected-result]

Comment: do you want the aside at the bottom of section. And they should be side by side?

Comment: I want the black `aside` on the left of the yellow `section` and the green `aside` on the right of the yellow `section`. That's what I tried to achieve using `order` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two changes needed. First aside tag is not empty tag and second there is issue with pesudo css selector

```css
body {
    width: 990px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: grey;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#main {
    display: flex;
}

aside {
    flex: 1;
    height: 400px;
}

#main aside:nth-child(2) {
    order: 1;
    background-color: red;
}
#main aside:nth-child(3) {
    order: 3;
    background-color: green;
}

section {
    background-color: yellow;
    flex: 2;
    order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"> <!-- "main" tag not supported in IE -->
    <section>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </p>
    </section>
    <aside></aside>
    <aside></aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, it works like a charm! Thank you very much! In addition to my mistake on child selectors, I did not think there was a difference between `<aside></aside>` and `<aside />`.